# Difference between dirty and pristine in redux-form?

Tags: redux, redux-form

This might be generic question as well, but talking specifically in terms of redux-forms, why are both dirty and pristine needed in the props. Wasnt it possible to only have one because both are exactly opposite of each other as given in the [documentation here](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/) ?

Comment: As I understand, there is no "dirty" option in redux form, the name is "pristine" and you set it to true or false, false meaning that the form is dirty

Comment: There is one, see the documentation, precisely the reason for my confusion

Comment: I'm quite confident, that dirty = !pristine in any case, see [source](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/src/Field.js#L63)